# write csv in python based on sub-string condition

Tags: python, string, csv, substring

I have the following `result` variable in a data frame (`df`) and I am trying to output a csv file for those that starts with "test"

```
abandoned
static
test_a_1
test_b_2
abandoned
test_b_3
```

The following code is not working. Thanks in advance for your insights

```
substr="test"
if substr in df['result']:
    df.to_csv("C:/Projects/result.csv",sep=',',index=False)
```

Comment: when you say not working do you mean it's not writing at all or writing the wrong thing?

Comment: Its not writing. The result of `substr in df['result']` is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want to make a csv that only contains the rows for which result starta with 'test', use the following:

```
df[df.result.str.contains('^test.*')].to_csv("C:/Projects/result.csv",sep=',',index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because "test_a_1" is in the list does not mean that "test" is, 
in Python logic.

Example of how Python evaluates "if [string] in [list]" statements:

```
>>> test = 'test1'
>>> testlist = ['test1', 'test2']
>>> if 'test' in test:
...     print('hi')
... 
hi
>>> if 'test' in testlist:
...     print('hi')
... 
>>>
```

This would work:

```
substr="test"
for val in df['result']:
    if substr in val:
        # Do stuff
        # And optionally (if you only need one CSV per dataframe rather than one CSV per result):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks Iroh.. This gives the output for all the result values, but I am interested to see `test_a_1`,`test_b_2`,`test_b_3` rows in csv.

Comment: Looks like scomes's solution works for that, plus it's a sexy one-liner. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```
df['temp'] = [1 if 'test' in df['result'][k] for k in df.index else 0]
df['result'][df['temp']==1].to_csv("/your/path", sep=',', index=False)
```